# Vuex mutate object best practices

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm developing a module that enables users to place remarks on an object. I use a Vuex store and a component to visualize the remarks. I've pasted the code below.

Thing is I bind the text area that displays the remark body to a v-model that is the property body of the remark object. Since I return the array of remarks from the store with the getremarks getter any changes to the remark object properties are directly changed in the store as well since it is the same object that gets passed around. I thereby effectively bypass the entire action/mutation pattern Vuex wants me to implement.

I can always pass the mutated remark to an action and mutation in the store but that means I'm mutating an object that is allready mutated. I was wondering if there are any best practices around?

**Store**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const model = {
    state: {
        remarks: [],
    },

    mutations: {
        SET_REMARKS(state, remarks) {
            state.remarks = remarks;
        }
    },

    getters: {
        getRemarks(state) {
            return state.remarks;
        },
        getRemarkById: (state) => (id) => {
            return state.remarks.find(remark => remark.model_remark_id === id);
        }
    },

    actions: {
        
    }
}

export default model;
```

**Component**

```
<template>
    <v-list two-line expand>
        <v-list-group v-for="remark in remarks" :key="remark.model_remark_id">
            <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon v-text="icon" :color="remark.priority === 1 ? 'red' : remark.priority === 2 ? 'orange' : '#1478c7'" />
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title><b>{{ remark.created_by_user.name  }}</b></v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle>Created at {{ moment(remark.created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:ss:mm')  }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </template>

            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    &nbsp;
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col>
                            <v-textarea
                                class="mx-2"
                                v-model="remark.body"
                                auto-grow
                            />
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col align="right">
                            <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            elevation="2"
                            @click="remarkDone(remark)"
                            >Done</v-btn>
                            &nbsp;
                            <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            elevation="2"
                            @click="remarkUpdate(remark)"
                            >Update</v-btn>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    data: () => ({
        icon: "mdi-comment"
    }),
    computed: {
        remarks: function () {
            return this.getRemarks();
        },
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapGetters([
            "getRemarks",
            "getRemarkById"
        ]),

        remarkUpdate(remark) {
            console.log(remark);

            const x = this.getRemarkById()(remark.model_remark_id);

            console.log(x);
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can clone the objects before using them in your component.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key principle to keep in mind here is separation of concerns. Let Vuex handle all mutations of the state and let your Vue component simply fetch the remarks from the state. The state is reactive, so if you call a mutation from your component to change your remarks, you want the component to simply react to that change and render the updated markup.

Also, you should use `mapGetters` to map your getters to `computed` properties, not methods. I'm also not sure if you need `getRemarkById` getter in `updateRemark()` since you already have the remark as an argument.

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ remarks: 'getRemarks' })
  },
  methods: {
    updateRemark(remark) {
      // here you should commit a mutation to update your remark
      this.$store.commit('updateRemark', remark)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does however feels like redundant logic calling a mutation for an object which is already changed. I can see the reactive argument though. Thanks for the headsup regarding the mapgetters in computed properties!

Comment: I can't see that you are changing the object inside the component. The user clicks the button to update the remark, which in turn calls the updateRemark method. At this point your remark object has not been touched. So you should be good as long as you let Vuex handle any mutations.

Comment: My bad, stripped some code but the remarkDone method touches the object, the remarkUpdate is merely to log info/save updates. I understand the importance of letting Vuex do the actual mutation 'which brings me back to the original question, what's a good way to mutate complex objects in a Vuex store. I can see a couple of options, cloning as IVO GELOV suggests above, touching the object and do it again in a mutation as your code example implies since it passes to allready touched object to a mutation. Both mean me implementing logic that shouldn't be necessary imho?

Comment: You are right, you shouldn't be implementing the same logic in your component and in a mutation. That's repetitive and not a desired pattern. In remarkDone, instead of touching the object, call a mutation to do it instead. After the mutation, the updated state is given to your component. For example, remarkDone(remark) { this.$store.commit('remarkDone', remark) }

Comment: Allright, seems I've got to work around Vuex a bit. Thanks for the input